# JavaScript Confirm on ASP.Net Button Control

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, popup

I working on an ASP.Net C# application, I wanted to create a Button Control, when user click on the button, a JavaScript confirm popup, then get the Boolean value from the user (Yes/No) to perform further actions in the button onClick event.

my current approach was added OnClientClick and OnClick event in the button, where OnClientClick trigger JavaScript function and the (Yes/No) value is store into HiddenField Control to make use during OnClick event.

It is something like the following code fragments:

```
function CreatePopup(){
            var value = confirm("Do you confirm?");
            var hdn1 = document.getElementById('hdn1');
            hdn1.Value = value;
        }

<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" onclick="Button1_Click" OnClientClick="CreatePopup()"/>
<asp:HiddenField ID="hdn1" runat="server" />
```

Is there any better approach in order to do this? thank you in advanced.

Comment: do you need to fire up a server event even if user say "no"?

Comment: Yes that is the requirement, see the comment to my answer!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Change your CreatePopup() function to return a boolean:

```
function CreatePopup()
{
    return confirm("Do you confirm?");
}
```

And then ensure you return that from the `OnClientClick()` in the button:

`<asp:Button ... OnClientClick="return CreatePopup();" />`

Using that method, the `OnClick()` method will only fire if the `OnClientClick()` method returns true.

Comment: thank you for your comment, I need to fire the OnClick() event all the time, so the solution above cannot apply in my situation :)

Comment: Why not just have two ASP buttons for the user instead of deferring their decision to the JS confirm?  Then you can put yes/no specific code in the handlers and call a common method for the rest.  If your solution works though and you're happy with it I see no reason to change it!

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to store the value of the JavaScript confirmation in the hidden field? Just simply return false in your JavaScript function when the confirm value is 'no' , to prevent the form from submitting. When cnfirm value is yes, return true to allow the form to be submitted. In your code behind in the button_click method you don't have to check what happened in your JavaScript confirm, since form will never be submitted if the user said no.

Comment: I wanted the Yes / No value everytime when user click on the Button, mean I always wanted OnClick() event to fire and need the Yes / No value, just why I stored it in hiddenfield